# Data impressa no formato errada

Tags: r, shiny

Estou desenvolvendo um app em shiny e estou com um problema na impressão data, tanto no navegador, quanto no arquivo .csv gerado. Ela fica nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código para a obtenção da data é

```
baseEstatistica[6,2] <- Sys.Date()
```

Outras datas geradas de forma diferente estão sendo impressas do mesmo jeito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer tudo numa linha de código. E muito mais legível. Existe um método `format.Date` para objetos de classe `"Date"`, basta usá-lo.
Tem ainda a vantagem de poder usar qualquer formato de datas, uma lista completa está [aqui](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) ou veja `help("strptime")`.

```
format(Sys.Date(), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "06/01/2020"

baseEstatistica[6,2] <- format(Sys.Date(), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Muito melhor, marquei como resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta foi mais simples do que eu imaginei, bastou utilizar um

```
baseEstatistica[6,2] <- as.character(Sys.Date())
```

Mas a data saiu no formato abaixo:

[image: Formato da data no código]

Atualizei o codigo da data para  o formato abaixo:

```
datavaalicao <- as.character(dataMesAvaliacao)
baseEstatistica[6,2] <- paste(str_sub(datavaalicao, 9,10),str_sub(datavaalicao, 6,7),str_sub(datavaalicao, 1,4), sep = "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas forma de formatação de data, seguem alguns exemplos e respetivas formações:
Formatando Datas

```
%d: dia do mês em 2 dígitos (13)
%m: mês em 2 digitos (01)
%y: ano em 2 dígitos (82)
%Y: ano em 4 dígitos (1982)
%A: dia da semana (Friday)
%a: dia da semana abreviado (Fri)
%B: mês (July)
%b: mês abreviado (Jul)
```

Formatando Time

```
%H: hora (00-23)
%M: minuto
%S: segundo
%T: formado reduzido para %H:%M:%S
```

Formatando a saída - as.Date()

```
as.Date("2016-06-28")
as.Date("20160628434")
as.Date("Jun-28-16", format = "%b-%d-%y")
as.Date("28 June, 2016", format = "%d %B, %Y")
```

Função format()

```
Sys.Date()
format(Sys.Date(), format = "%d %B, %Y")
format(Sys.Date(), format = "Hoje é %A!")
```

Convertendo Datas - as.POSIXct

```
date1 <- "Jun 13, '96 hours:23 minutes:01 seconds:45"
date1_convert <- as.POSIXct(date1, format = "%B %d, '%y hours:%H minutes:%M 
seconds:%S")
date1_convert
```

Operações com Datas

```
data_de_hoje <- as.Date("2016-06-25", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
data_de_hoje
data_de_hoje + 1

my_time <- as.POSIXct("2016-05-14 11:24:134")
my_time
my_time + 1

data_de_hoje - as.Date(my_time)
data_de_hoje - my_time
```

Convertendo Data em formato específico

```
dts = c(1127056501,1104295502,1129233601,1113547501,1119826801,
1132519502,1125298801,1113289201)
mydates = dts
class(mydates) = c('POSIXt','POSIXct')
mydates

mydates = structure(dts,class=c('POSIXt','POSIXct'))
mydates
```

Função ISODate

```
b1 = ISOdate(2011,3,23)
b1
b2 = ISOdate(2012,9,19)
b2
b2 - b1

difftime(b2, b1, units='weeks')
```

Pacote lubridate

```
ymd("20160604") 
mdy("06-04-2016") 
dmy("04/06/2016")

chegada <- ymd_hms("2016-06-04 12:00:00", tz = "Pacific/Auckland")
partida <- ymd_hms("2011-08-10 14:00:00", tz = "Pacific/Auckland")

chegada
partida

second(chegada)
second(chegada) <- 23
chegada
wday(chegada)
wday(chegada, label = TRUE)
class(chegada)
interval(chegada, partida)

tm1.lub <- ymd_hms("2016-05-24 23:55:26")
tm1.lub

tm2.lub <- mdy_hm("05/25/16 08:32")
tm2.lub

year(tm1.lub)
week(tm1.lub)

tm1.dechr <- hour(tm1.lub) + minute(tm1.lub)/60 + second(tm1.lub)/3600
tm1.dechr
force_tz(tm1.lub, "Pacific/Auckland")
```